# Autocomplete - как заменить ul на div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Есть стандартный шаблон jQuery Autocomplete c такой структурой подсказок в поиске: ul -> li, но не могу понять, как изменить ul на div. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

```
        .data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem =
            function (ul, item) {
                return $('<li>')
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .addClass("mse2-ac-wrapper")
                    .append($("<div>").addClass('mse2-ac-link').html(item.label))
                    //.append("<a class=\"mse2-ac-link\">" + item.label + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
            };
```

Comment: Укажите только [*минимальный* воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), не весь ваш проект.

Comment: Оставил часть кода, которая генерирует сам шаблон, но тут, как я понимаю, нельзя поменять тег ul на другой, а в документации ничего не могу найти

Comment: Судя по коду, вы вряд ли учли что это должен быть **воспроизводимый пример**.